# Swiper.js: delay parameter ignored

Tags: swiper.js

I'm creating a simple slideshow using swiper.js.

My config looks like this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper( '#swiper-container',
                               {
                                   autoplay: {
                                       delay : 400000
                                   },
                                   loop: true,
                                   speed: 2800,
                                   grabCursor : true

                               }
                             );
```

This pretty much works... except that the 'delay' parameter gets ignored.

I've also tried putting the 'delay' parameter outside of the autoplay object, like this:

v

```
ar mySwiper = new Swiper( '#swiper-container',
                               {
                                   autoplay: true,
                                   delay: 4000,
                                   loop: true,
                                   speed: 2800,
                                   grabCursor : true

                               }
                             )
```

;

This doesn't help. The delay value is ignored.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Your first example should be initializing correctly. Are you sure that `#swiper-container` is present in the HTML?

Answer (score 6):

The way you wrote it should work, according to Swiper official documentation. But you can also try to set the delay as the autoplay value, it should do the trick:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper( '#swiper-container', {
    autoplay: 4000,
    loop: true,
    speed: 2800,
    grabCursor : true
});
```

The code above has been tested with the current Swiper version (4.1.0).

Answer (score 2):

`autoplay : 4000`  // works for 3.x.x version

`autoplay : false` or `{ delay:4000,  ....}`  // works for 4.x.x versions

full details are on github docs

Comment: Please try to use code block for formatting and include the link.

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay takes a boolean value, that's not an option
Instead, I've found a working option. It's pretty clear in documentation

So you just have to add this parameter to your ***div class="swiper-slide"*** and it'll work:

***data-swiper-autoplay="2000"***

Answer (score 0):

this is useful information, and it works. thank you.
**for 3.x.x version. I add below like this.**

```
autoplay : 4000,
speed: 300,
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import it.

```
import Swiper, {Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay} from 'swiper';
```